# meteor js how to write a file to disk from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am writing a meteor package 'myPackage' which needs to write a file onto disk using Npm FileSystem and Pah modules.
The file should end up in the example-app/packages/myPackage/auto_generated/myFile.js, where example-app project
has myPackage added.

```
fs = Npm.require( 'fs' ) ;
path = Npm.require( 'path' ) ;

Meteor.methods( {
    autoGenerate : function( script ) {
        var myPath = '/Users/martinfox/tmp/auto-generated' ;
        var filePath = path.join(myPath, 'myFile.js' ) ;
                    console.log( filePath ) ;    // shows /Uses/martinfox/tmp/auto-generated/myFile.js 
        var buffer = new Buffer( script ) ;
        fs.writeFileSync( filePath, buffer ) ;
    },
} );
```

When I run the code above (server side only) I get

```
Exception while invoking method 'autoGenerate' Error: ENOENT, 
no such file or directory '/Uses/martinfox/tmp/auto-generated/myFile.js'
```

Note /Uses/martinfox/tmp/auto-generated folder does exist

1. Any ideas what is going wrong?
2. Is it possible to obtain the absolute path to the meteor projects directory?

Comment: Are you sure your directory begins with /Uses and not /Users?

Comment: Also, regarding your second question, __dirname will give you the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in

Comment: @CBlanchard Sorry my bad typo Question 1 now works but I don't seem to be able to get var filePath = path.join( __dirname + 'test, myFile.txt)

Comment: I get ref error __dirname undefined. Also tried fs.__dirname

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the path of your project you can do this :
from main.js stored in the root of your app

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
__ROOT_APP_PATH__ = fs.realpathSync('.');
console.log(__ROOT_APP_PATH__);
```

You can also check if your folder exists :

```
if (!fs.existsSync(myPath)) {
    throw new Error(myPath + " does not exists");
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I had to make your first line var fs = Npm.require('fs') to avoid a 'not defined error' on 'require('fs')'. Then I received a path of '/Users/martinfox/Desktop/WEB-DEV/METEOR/Managers/my-example/.meteor/local/build/programs/server' from which I was able to extract up to and including '/my-example/' from the returned  __ROOT_APP_PATH__ to get the root folder of the app's project, which is exactly what I needed so thanks and answered.

Comment: I modified the require to correct it. One more thing, each time you run meteor it will remove previous installation, so you have to store files outside meteor folders. but that was what you were expected to do with the /Users...

Comment: Let's say I had written a helloworld.txt into the __ROOT_APP_PATH__ How to store files outside meteor folders, preferable /public? Thanks.

Comment: @KaiFengChew If you want to write files outside meteorJs app, just do a fs.appendFile(__ROOT_APP_PATH__ + '/../whereyouwant')

Answer (score 4):

If you are just looking for the absolute path for your app, you could simply do `var base = process.env.PWD`, which yields: `/Users/[username]/[app-name]`

This would avoid the extra stuff `.meteor/local/build/programs/server`

Comment: But, you will have problems after build your app because there is no `process.env.PWD` in a bundle app.

Comment: @paulequilibrio just store it as a global variable before it gets bundled