# Meteor application access files outside its root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

The intention is to access a library of images outside the meteor application directory. This is the case since the application will not be the only component using the said lib. The meteor app, images lib and other components will reside on the same machine.

How can I do this? And is there such a thing called a local content delivery network?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by a local CDN? And by access, do you mean serve the images or write to the directory? Please be specific about what you need.

Comment: By access, yes I meant both serving images and writing to the external directory. In terms of CDN (I'm not sure if it's the correct concept),  let's just say I need an external component which will host/serve images to different applications, for example, where my meteor application can get images from.

Answer (score 0):

You need two different things at the same time.

For the **first part**, to read/write access your files outside the meteor directory, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20330021/1064151 and http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/accessing-the-file-system-in-meteor/ which basically tells you to use `fs` from `npm`

```
@fs = Npm.require 'fs'
@path = Npm.require 'path'

readSomeFile = () ->
  p = path.resolve './server/somefile.csv'
  data = fs.readFileSync p, 'UTF-8'
  #...
```

The **second part** is to serve those images from an alternative web server which you can do with any web server module from node or apache/nginx that uses the target directory as its docbase.

You can even do that from within meteor but meteor is not the best web server to serve static assets.